# Core Data: Predicate-based validation

Tags: ios, macos, core-data, nspredicate

I'm working on managed object validation. So far I'm done with property-level validation. Now I'm meditating above inter-property validation. I could do it by one big if-else control flow but wondering if there is more elegant option.

I've found `NSValidationPredicateErrorKey` with

> For predicate-based validation, key for the predicate for the
>   condition that failed to validate.

in documentation.

Somehow I sense this could be my pick, but I've found nothing on this topic. I searched official documentation, SO, reputable blogs, Core Data book by Marcus S. Zarra.

So what is predicate-based validation? Does it even exist? Is it even relevant if not documented? What are the use cases? If inter-propery validation, what is the example?

Comment: What you mean by `inter-property validation`?

Comment: ["There are two types of validation—property-level and inter-property. You use property-level validation to ensure the correctness of individual values; you use inter-property validation to ensure the correctness of combinations of values."](http://goo.gl/SyyqJ3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply override `validateForInsert` and `validateForUpdate` in your managed object subclasses to implement inter-property validation, as shown in the documentation to be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdValidation.html) (with code example).

The "predicate-based" validation can be achieved via the rich managed object API. Each `NSManagedObject` has an associated `NSEntityDescription` (a property called `entity`). Via this you can get to the `NSPropertyDescription` of each property. Property descriptions in turn have a property called `validationPredicates`, an array of `NSPredicates` for validation. Please note that these are read-only and they are primarily used for informing the error objects in case of validation errors. Also, to my understanding, they cannot always describe adequately the validation happening in the overrides mentioned above.

In summary, this error key you found is not really an indication that there is a generic, predicate-based way of specifying validation constraints. Instead you will have to override the above methods in the managed object classes.

Comment: Sure. But my question is what the documentation means by "predicate-based validation".

Comment: Right. I extended my answer to explain.